# Outlook emails extra space in TD cells

Tags: html, html-table, outlook, html-email, outlook-2007

Outlook is making everything taller, and also the text goes to 4 lines. I would like the tests to come the same.

See image, the right-hand side, everything is bigger except the font size and leading.

I tried setting line height to 0 and then to 1. It didn't make a difference.
Thanks!

```
 <tr>
    <td class="" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: none;-moz-hyphens: none;hyphens: none;border-collapse: collapse;line-height:20px;font-size:20px" height="20px" valign="top" bgcolor="red">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;word-break: break-word;-webkit-hyphens: none;-moz-hyphens: none;hyphens: none;" bgcolor="blue">
       <div class="mktoText" id="" mktoName="" style="line-height: 30px;font-weight: 400; color: #ffffff; font-size:19px;letter-spacing: 0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices gravida. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis.
       </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

[image: spacing]

Comment: Outlook 2007 is no longer supported even by Microsoft. Are you sure you have to subject yourself to this misery?

Comment: I should edit, it happens in all Microsoft email tests I ran

Comment: Which email clients are you comparing against Outlook? When I compare Outlook 2016 to Apple Mail in Litmus, there is a negligible difference which I would accept considering it's Outlook. I honestly would say that you'll never get anything to align perfectly. Remember that each email client has it's own rendering engine that even differs between OSs (e.g. Gmail iOS vs Gmail Android), so don't expect everything to be mirrored exactly, everywhere.

Comment: basically all Mac vs Microsoft. These differences add up, and I try to minimize them as much as possible. If not, I work around it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be just that the table is taking less width in Outlook than your other application. Specifying for example `<table width="300">`, is as @Digital_Frankenstein said, negligible difference.

I did notice that when using `line-height:60px` or any pixel value, Outlook renders the text at the bottom of the line:

[image: Outlook render at bottom of line]

But when using just a number without digits, e.g. `line-height:3`, Outlook renders the text at the top of the line! (Same as with percentages, e.g. 300%.)

[image: Outlook render at top of line]

(Using 'em' seems to be noticeably different - smaller - in Outlooks, and renders at the bottom.)

You may need to specify a margin to the div to get them to line up consistently (normally, it is imperceptible since line-heights are typically quite small).

But also consider that nobody is going to be comparing Outlook to Gmail/Apple Mail etc. when looking at your email. So your aim is not pixel perfection, but rather a consistent *experience*, adapted to each email environment (mobile, desktop, inside/outside, iOS/Android, etc.)

**Blank lines**

I've always used a paragraph on a blank line, to get the same height there cross-email environment:

`<td bgcolor="red"><p style="font-size:20px;line-height: 20px;">&nbsp;</p></td>`